# SSIS Excel Connection manager validation is taking forever

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

SSIS Excel Connection manager validation is taking forever. The same package works when running Visual Studio in administrator mode. The Excel file I am reading is from a local folder.
I set the Security of both Package and project to "DontSaveSensitive"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling SSIS Package Validation when Loading a Package in the VS Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942985/disabling-ssis-package-validation-when-loading-a-package-in-the-vs-designer)

Answer (score 0):

After spending almost the whole day, I found out that the TargetServerVersion did not match the target SQL server. Fixing that resolves the issue.